# Random Query Zend

Tags: random, records

I search lot but not getting any help on random records with mysql.I am using random query to get random data from database with not in with some limit. If database contains 100 records and suppose I am giving 30 as limit with random function and some not in id.My problem is that when it hit first time I am giving not in id as empty and it is giving me 30 records randomly.But for second time except last 30 records i.e(it is in not in variable) it should give me another 30 records from 70 records but it is giving me less than 30 i.e(28,29).This because first it applies random function and limit and then filter it with not in.My query is like below:

```
$subQuery = $this->select()

->from(array('s' => 'shop'), array('s.shop_id','b.shop_name','b.shop_template_id'))
->order('RAND()')
->where('s.shop_id NOT in (?)', $shop_id)
->limit(30);

$query = $this->select() 

->from(array('b' => $subQuery), array('*'))
->join(array('p' => 'product'), 's.shop_id = p.shop_id', array('p.product_price'))
->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$resultRows = $this->fetchAll($query);
```

Update: I got the problem why it is giving (28,29) records sometime because join query contains product for shop and if some shop is having 0 products it does not get that shop.My question is that irrespective of product how can i get that shop from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you join instead of left join. Also there's no need for a sub select. This should work:

```
$objSelect = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$objSelect->from(
    array('s' => 'shop'),
    array('s.shop_id','b.shop_name','b.shop_template_id')
);
$objSelect->joinLeft(
    array('p' => 'product'),
    's.shop_id = p.shop_id',
    array('p.product_price')
);
$objSelect->order('RAND()');
$objSelect->limit(30);
$objRowSet = $this->fetchAll($objSelect);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer one more thing,we want it should fetch shop randomly it doing but by default it applies asc.We dont want any asc and desc condition it should get random shop from whole database from anywhere.We tried ->order('RAND()')
->order('shop_name DESC')
->order('shop_id DESC') still not giving random data.any suggestion.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, sorry. If you use order by rand(), the records will be returned in a random order. If you add another order, you won't get them randomized - in that case you'll have to wrap your first (random) query in a subselect and apply another order on a select from that. But you seem to ask for random order, and you should get that from just using the code above.

Comment: above RAND() function gives random records in ascending order by default,and we dont want that,it should pick random data from any order and not in ascending or descending.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you further. Order by rand() should return records in a random order and does so for me. There might be other reasons your result set is sorted I guess (sub selects, Zend extensions of the DB Class and whatnot) that you're not telling us about, but you can then fix it by shuffling the rowset->toArray(). Examples for multi dimension arrays and preserving keys are in the comments here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php